# Count occurrances of a word before another phrase in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the number of times `\n` appears in string `(Student Copy)\nfor\nspecial school\n...Shaping the Future\n408,)` before the phrase `Shaping the Future`. Is there a way to do it without splitting the string?

Output in this case should be 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the string up until your substring of interest, and then use `count`

```
s = """(Student Copy)\nfor\nspecial school\n...Shaping the Future\n408,)""" 
s[:s.index("Shaping the Future")].count('\n')
```